# Change value of all undefined variables in a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object that looks something like this:

```
object =
spacing
    undefined
spacingOptions
    "Standard"
spacinginches
    "2"
```

I want to change all instances of when it's undefined to `''` an empty string, is there a function that does that?

Comment: Only enumerable properties or non-enumerable too? Only own properties or inherited too? In the latter case, should `''` be set in the target object or in the ancestor one? And what about accessor properties? And symbol properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or with a simple loop:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
  if (obj[prop] === undefined) {
    obj[prop] = '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this to unlimited levels deep?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over it using `Object.keys` and `foreach`, and then use an if conditional to see if you have an undefined value.

```
Object.keys(object).forEach(function(item) {
  if (typeof object[item] === undefined) {
    object[item] = '';
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
for(var key in object){
    object[key] = (object[key] !== undefined) ? object[key] : '';
}
```